# Тогда большие птицы разлетались над пустырем. Запрыгали кузнечики(,) и поползли гусеницы

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

- Нужна ли запятая здесь? Какое есть правило, чтобы доказать?

Думается, запятая перед **и** не нужна, но не уверена. В предыдущем предложении есть слово тогда, его можно считать общим членом, а второе предложение считать парцеллированным. Зависит ли пунктуация парцеллированного предложения от первого, или это вообще не парцеллированное предложение...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с запятой не вызовет никаких вопросов: (1) **Тогда большие птицы разлетЕлись над пустырем. Запрыгали кузнечики, и поползли гусеницы.**

Примечание: изменен вид глагола.

Формально эти предложения являются самостоятельными, **но смысловая парцелляция здесь есть.** При таком оформлении мы разбиваем предикативные части на две смысловые группы по сравнению с предложением: (2) Тогда большие птицы разлетелись над пустырем,  **запрыгали кузнечики и поползли гусеницы.**

Однако у автора может появиться желание **интонационно объединить две последние предикативные основы и не поставить запятую.** Такое оформление будет **авторским**, в правилах оно не прописано, но смысловая задача понятна:

Тогда большие птицы разлетелись над пустырем. **Запрыгали кузнечики и поползли гусеницы**. Автор считает, что ***тогда*** относится и ко второму предложению тоже.

Или: Тогда большие птицы разлетелись над пустырем; **запрыгали кузнечики и поползли гусеницы**.